# Is 'repeater' in this angular tutorial a jasmine concept?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine, angularjs

Looking through angular js [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04), I do not understand where the repeater (function?) comes from in a jasmine test. Is this a jasmine or an angular construct?

The page does have an ng-repeat attribute in a `<li>` element - but I dont see how that translates to the reference to 'repeater' in the test

```
  it('should be possible to control phone order via the drop down select box',
    function() {
    //let's narrow the dataset to make the test assertions shorter
    input('query').enter('tablet');

    //where does  'repeater' below come from?
    expect(repeater('.phones li', 'Phone List').column('phone.name')).
    toEqual(["Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi",
    "MOTOROLA XOOM\u2122"]);

    select('orderProp').option('Alphabetical');


    expect(repeater('.phones li', 'Phone List').column('phone.name')).
    toEqual(["MOTOROLA XOOM\u2122",
    "Motorola XOOM\u2122 with Wi-Fi"]);
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `repeater` is not a Jasmine construct, it is AngularJS e2e scenario tester concept.

The `repeater` function is defined in the DSL used by the AngularJS e2e scenario runner and its definition can be seen here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngScenario/dsl.js#L249
The corresponding documentation is located at: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing

It should be noted that even if AngularJS uses Jasmine syntax for its end-to-end test, those e2e tests are *not* Jasmine tests, they just happen to use very similar syntax. The purpose of the AngularJS `ngScenario` runner is to execute end-to-end tests in a browser and uses matchers are tight to the browser environment (DOM, location etc.) Jasmine is more focused on unit-tests and has matchers for JavaScript objects.

The mentioned `repeater` is just a way of counting DOM object given a jQuery selector and it is true that is usually used to count DOM element produced by the `ngRepeat` directive.