# what is the "expect" function used in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the Angular documentation they write this:

`expect(scope.counter).toEqual(0);`

and this was written in many places like [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest).

I just want to know what it does

Comment: That's to run [tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is [Jasmine](https://github.com/jasmine) unit testing framework syntax for [unit tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). Angular uses, promotes  and encourages [unit testing practices](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.unit-testing).

Testability is taken very seriously in AngularJS and the authors of the framework make sure that code written using AngularJS is easy to test:

- Built-in dependency injection (DI) system makes it easy to combine an application from smaller, well tested elements
- Accompanying tooling - [Testacular](https://github.com/vojtajina/testacular) - makes it easy to write and execute tests in practice

AngularJS has also a solution for higher-level, [end-to-end testing](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.e2e-testing). E2e tests use a very similar syntax (so you will also notice the `expect` keyword) but those are not Jasmine tests. More info can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13213262/1418796

Answer (score 7):

[Here is the documentation for `expect`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Expectations).

Answer (score 4):

this is part of the test.
it is described in https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/e2e-testing

Not all details are present, so you may want to look into the source code.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/lathonez/clicker/issues/159 helps explain as well. I had to add:   "types": [
      "jasmine"
    ], 
to my tsconfig.json as it was unable to find "expect"